# How to boot from USB on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, boot, live-usb

For some reason, my ubuntu 14.04LTS started messing up and now the sidebar and menu bar does not show up after I log in. I am new to ubuntu so I don't know much about the code, but to fix my computer I created a live usb and tried to boot from it. I don't know why, but the usb is not being recognized and the computer starts up normally. I tried changing the boot order but the usb is not on the list. Please help!

Thank you!!

Comment: instead of booting from live usb you can resintall you desktop and your problem may go away

Answer (score 0):

try this, missing sidebar and menu bar may come back:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your BIOS setup to boot from the peripheral sources (floppy, USB, CD etc.) before HDD. How to do that:
While booting - hit F2, F8 or F12 (depending on your system) to get to startup menu. Then go through the menu to select an order of the boot - you have to set it up the way that USB boot is initiated BEFORE a HDD boot.
Some BIOS do not allow to boot from USB at all. If it's your case - please consider to use CD instead of USB while selecting CD booting before HDD boot. Hope this help.